# Can't get setBackgroundMessageHandler to work

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

In [react-native-firebase v6](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), I can't get `setBackgroundMessageHandler` to work in my app. Notifications are received just fine but the handler is not executed.

I have done it like in the [guide](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging/reference/module#setBackgroundMessageHandler) to no avail.

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async ({ data: { title, message } }) => {
    console.log('in background');
    // Save the notification locally
    const notificationList = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@SM_NOTIFICATIONS')) || [];
    notificationList.push({ title, message, isRead: false });
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@SM_NOTIFICATIONS', JSON.stringify(notificationList));
});
```

Nothing happened beside the incoming notifications. I expected the code to save the incoming notifications in `AsyncStorage`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay. After consulting the developer's team, I finally figure this one out.

First, `setBackgroundMessageHandler` must be called before `registerComponent`.

Second, **don't send notification data. Only send custom data (silent push).** Hence, you need to use local notification instead of push notification to display the notification in system tray.

Because Firebase Console somehow doesn't support silent push, I used [FCM API v1](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8) to send data-only. Here is my example:

`POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/messages:send`

```
{
    "validate_only": false,
    "message": {
        "name": "XXX",
        "data": {
            "title": "BG 2",
            "message": "BG BARU"
        },
        "topic": "C3166"
    }
}
```

As you can see, no `notification` field in JSON above.

Comment: "First, setBackgroundMessageHandler must be called before registerComponent" where did you get that? why it's not documented?

Comment: @TuanDatTran tbh I already forget why. I think I get it from trial and error.

Comment: It is documented, check it out [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background--quit-state-messages). _To setup a background handler, call the setBackgroundMessageHandler outside of your application logic as early as possible._

Comment: setBackgroundMessageHandler is working in iOS for you. Its not triggered in my app when App is closed.

Comment: So how would you get notifications when app is closed?

Comment: SOLUTION - I was struggling with this for some time. Removing the notification from the payload solved the problem! Thank you Dorklord